# Write HTML to screen with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, document

I'm very new to JavaScript and HTML I and need some help!

I'm trying to write a table in JavaScript, that writes into the page HTML, and then importing that function to a HTML file to show the table.

I have this in a JavaScript file

```
function createTable()
{
    var table = "<table>";

    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<th><center>Title</center></th>";
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td><center> data </center></td>";
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</table>";

    document.write(table);

}
```

And then I specify the src and call the function in a html file like so:

```
<head>
<script scr = "source/file.js" type=text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        createTable()
    </script>
</body>
```

Although this works, I've heard that using document.write() is a very bad practice.

I have tried using table = `document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML;` and then in the HTML file used `<div id="tablePrint"></div>` however my table doesn't show. I've also tried `document.body.appendChild(table);` but that doesn't work either.

Is using `document.write()` ok? Or is their a better way to write my table to the HTML on screen.

Comment: Use `var table = document.createElement('table'); document.body.appendChild(table);` and do similar things to `tr` and `td`. And avoid `document.write()` as it overwrite any exist contents in the page.

Comment: You are not terminating your strings properly. And using `document.write` is not bad practice... most of the time you will be appending your elements to other nodes, so it is just rare that you need to use it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have your function return the table as a string.

```
function createTable()
{
    var table = "<table>";

    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<th><center>Title</center></th>";
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td><center> data </center></td>";
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</table>";

    return table;

}
```

Assuming you don't want to overwrite the body completely create a `div` have it styled the way you want and just add the table content there.

```
<body>
<div id="table"></div>
    <script>
       var table=createTable();
       document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=table;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's hacking, but not coding, to create HTML elements as a strings. This can be okay for a quick hack, but not as a best practice approach.

Comment: @user2182349 I don't understand one thing where have i mentioned that this is the best practice approach? I just gave the OP a solution to his existing code and problems. If you guys really have better solutions provide em pleAse and let the OP select it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some double quotes in your example. I'd suggest you to use JQuery:

```
$(function() { // After the HTML content loads
  var table = "<table>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<th><center>Title</center></th>";
  table += "</tr>";
  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td><center> data </center></td>";
  table += "</tr>";
  table += "</table>";

  $('body').append(table); // Appends HTML to an element
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/Ld6a94vt/).

And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) is why document.write() is not a good practice

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an
>   HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: jQuery is overkill. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is a right way to go :-)

Comment: It's not an overkill. Like in everything you have advantages and disadvantages of using JQuery over Vanilla JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<center>` element is obsolete since 1999 when HTML 4 came out. It's abolutely amazing that people (amateurs?) are still trying to use it. Let me cite from the [Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center):

> This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the CSS text-align property, which can be applied to the `<div>` element or to an individual `<p>`. For centering blocks, use other CSS properties like `margin-left` and `margin-right` and set them to auto (or set margin to 0 auto).

Normally, we don't use `document.write` for creating HTML content since it does not allow to control where the content is inserted. Rather, we use suitable DOM attributes (such as `innerHTML`) and methods (such as `appendChild`).

The proper way of creating an HTML `table` and inserting it into the HTML `body` element is using the DOM methods [insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell), as in the following code example:

```
function createTable() {
  var i=0, rowEl=null,
      tableEl = document.createElement("table");
  // create 10 table rows, each with two cells
  for (i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
    rowEl = tableEl.insertRow();  // DOM method for creating table rows
    rowEl.insertCell().textContent = "table cell "+ i +"-1" ;      
    rowEl.insertCell().textContent = "table cell "+ i +"-2" ;      
  }
  document.body.appendChild( tableEl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `document.write()` method for this purpose is not preferred. The most preferred way to do this with pure JavaScript is to use the `appendChild()` method.

Try this :

```
var table = document.createElement("table");  //Creating the <table> element
var tr1 = document.createElement("tr"); //Creating the first <tr> element
var tr2 = document.createElement("tr");  //Creating the second <tr> element
var th = document.createElement("th");  //Creating a <th> element
var td = document.createElement("td");  //Creating a <td> element
var text1 = document.createTextNode("Title"); //Creating the content of <th>
var text2 = document.createTextNode("data");  //Creating the content of <Ttd element

document.body.appendChild(table);  //The <body> is adopting the <table>
table.appendChild(tr1); //The <table> is adopting the first <tr>
tr1.appendChild(th);  //The first <tr> is adopting the <th>
table.appendChild(tr2);  //The <table> is adopting the second <tr>
tr2.appendChild(td);  //The second <tr> is adopting the <td>

th.appendChild(text1);  //<th> is adopting its content
td.appendChild(text2);  //<td> is adopting its content
```

> `<center>` tag is deprecated now, don't use it, use CSS instead.

Working [demo](https://jsbin.com/pamuta/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Using the DOM methods `insertRow`and `insertCell` instead of a large series of `appendChild`, as in my answer, leads to more concise and more readable code.